# How would I detect cobblestone being generated with Bukkit?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Ok, so I'm making a Bukkit plugin, that should detect cobblestone generators, keep in mind, that I don't want to prevent players from making cobblestone generators, I just want to get the block from the event, so I can do other stuff with that cobblestone.

What I've tried so far:

- BlockFromToEvent(Doesn't find cobblestone, only finds STATIONARY_LAVA to AIR)
- BlockFormEvent(It only found snow forming on the ground)

What I want to do:

- I want to detect blocks of cobblestone generated from water+lava combo
- I want to get their location/position/coordinates

Can you please at least point me in the right direction? I've been pulling out my hair for almost 3 hours already.

Thanks to everyone for the help!

EDIT: Solution in the picture below, will retype if requested!
[image: solution]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Good answer from FireBlast709 at Bukkit Forums](https://bukkit.org/threads/blocking-cobblestone-generators.120924/#post-1490274)

This will cancel any cobblestone generation. Basically, if you want to manipulate the cobblestone, you change the cancel line (indicated) to whatever you need.

---

```
@EventHandler
public void onFromTo(BlockFromToEvent event){
    Material type = event.getBlock().getType();
    if (type == Material.WATER || type == Material.STATIONARY_WATER || type == Material.LAVA || type == Material.STATIONARY_LAVA){
        Block b = event.getToBlock();
        if (b.getType() == Material.AIR){
            if (generatesCobble(type, b)){
                /* DO WHATEVER YOU NEED WITH THE COBBLE */
                event.setCancelled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

private final BlockFace[] faces = new BlockFace[]{
        BlockFace.SELF,
        BlockFace.UP,
        BlockFace.DOWN,
        BlockFace.NORTH,
        BlockFace.EAST,
        BlockFace.SOUTH,
        BlockFace.WEST
    };

public boolean generatesCobble(Material type, Block b){
    Material mirrorID1 = (type == Material.WATER || type == Material.STATIONARY_WATER ? Material.LAVA : Material.WATER);
    Material mirrorID2 = (type == Material.WATER || type == Material.STATIONARY_WATER ? Material.STATIONARY_LAVA : Material.STATIONARY_WATER);
    for (BlockFace face : faces){
        Block r = b.getRelative(face, 1);
        if (r.getType() == mirrorID1 || r.getType() == mirrorID2){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ok, first of all, thanks for an answer, but in the post I specified something: "Ok, so I'm making a Bukkit plugin, that should detect cobblestone generators, keep in mind, that I don't want to prevent players from making cobblestone generators," Still thanks for answering.

Comment: And I don't understand how this doesn't answer your question? It's explicitally saying that you should replace the `event.setCancelled(true)` with whatever you need in your code

Comment: therefore, not cancelling it

Comment: @Kerooker I've edited your answer to use `Material` instead of numeric IDs, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @MGlolenstine You should use this approach instead of the one you made.  It's cleaner and handles a few more situations than yours (for instance, smooth stone generation, and situations where lava flows at water instead of the other way around).  Although there may be a few other situations that it doesn't cover (water flowing into a torch and replacing it with cobble, for instance - the check if it is `AIR` may be incorrect).  All you need to do is tweak the `setCancelled` portion.

Comment: @Pokechu22 I don't mind, I posted the answer exactly as it is in the original answer (magic values also bother me), i thought it would be a problem to change. Thanks!

Comment: True, but all I wanted was to detect cobblestone, so I can replace it with air or something else

Comment: In this example, the cobble is being detected and the event is being cancelled. you should change the cancel part to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the BlockFromToEvent and do something like

```
if ((
     (event.getBlock().getType()==Material.LAVA)||         
     (event.getBlock().getType()==Material.WATER)||
     (event.getBlock().getType()==Material.STATIONARY_LAVA)||
     (event.getBlock().getType()==Material.STATIONARY_WATER)
    ) && event.getToBlock().getType()==Material.COBBLESTONE) {
        //do what you want
    }
```

Comment: Well... Sadly that won't work... [This](http://prntscr.com/fatar9) is what happens.

Answer (score 0):

There are specific events that can catch up with when Cobble is created. Mine Events, Crafting events, Pickup events. Each of these events should let you fetch which block was broken and check if it was an instance or material of Cobblestone.

Comment: I needed to get it when it was generated no when it was mined, crafted(didn't know you can craft cobblestone) or pickup. I wanted to replace it with something else when it was generated.